# Lean Node.js + Nginx server infrastructure for a mobile app?

Tags: performance, git, node.js, nginx, webserver

I am working on my own first mobile app which should be native on Android, iOS and also a web app which runs inside the mobile browser. I plan to use NodeJS and nginx should serve my files, git should be used to push new code to the nodes. My only problem is i have only access to **1 root server** with following specs:

Intel Core i7 2600 Quad core
32 GB RAM
2x 3 Terabyte Hard Drive in Software RAID
Unlimited Traffic

My plan is to build own NodeJS modules for the infrastructure of the app and render everything on the clientside with express & dust.js or modify.js.

My question is how to get mutiple nginx and NodeJS server´s as scale out setup, with less overhead to sqeeze most out out of this single machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For nginx, I think you just need to make sure you have the `accept_mutex` setting enabled and enable 4 worker processes

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3436969/266795
- for node.js, use the built-in [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module to run one process per core

In any case, that server is plenty capable of handling massive traffic for most sites/apps. Given this is your first mobile app, your odds of having traffic and workload to outgrow that much server power are near-zero. Don't sweat it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Peter i will try out your suggestions, i am just a little bit paranoid about scalability because my first web-sites were all LAMP based and i had no clue how to built an infrastructure which provides great scalability and now i don´t want to make the same mistakes again. I am also interested to use git for website/app code updates, or is there a faster and safer way to archive this?

Comment: Opinions vary widely about deployment and devops tactics. I recommend http://www.12factor.net/ principles myself and keep strict separation between source code version control and my build/distribute/deploy mechanics, but YMMV.

Comment: Great post, i will study these principles, to follow them on my app project. Thanks for your help so far.