# Why is HttpContext.Current null after await?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have the following test WebAPI code, I don't use WebAPI in production but I made this because of a discussion I had on this question: [WebAPI Async question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18367483/1981387)

Anyways, here's the offending WebAPI method:

```
public async Task<string> Get(int id)
{
    var x = HttpContext.Current;
    if (x == null)
    {
        // not thrown
        throw new ArgumentException("HttpContext.Current is null");
    }

    await Task.Run(() => { Task.Delay(500); id = 3; });

    x = HttpContext.Current;
    if (x == null)
    {
        // thrown
        throw new ArgumentException("HttpContext.Current is null");
    }

    return "value";
}
```

I had hereto believed that the second exception is expected because when the `await` completes, it will likely be on a different thread where `HttpContext.Current` as a thread-static variable will no longer resolve to the appropriate value. Now, based on the synchronization context, it could actually be forced to go back to the same thread after the await but I'm not doing anything fancy in my test. This is just a plain, naive use of `await`.

In comments in another question I was told that `HttpContext.Current` should resolve after an await. There's even another comment on this question indicating the same. So what's true? Should it resolve? I think no, but I want an authoritative answer on this because `async` and `await` is new enough that I can't find anything definitive.

TL;DR: Is `HttpContext.Current` potentially `null` after an `await`?

Comment: Your question is unclear - you've said what you expected to happen, and the comments indicate that that *is* what's happening... so what's confusing you?

Comment: @user2674389, this is misleading. It's `AspNetSynchronizationContext` that takes care of `HttpContext`, not `await`. More, the continuation callback for `await` may (and most likely will) occur on a different thread for Web API execution model.

Comment: edited to pose a succinct question

Comment: Don't use HttpContext in Web API. It isn't supported for all hosts.  There are alternative ways to do what HttpContext is used for.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what these alternative ways might be, @DarrelMiller? That would be useful...

Comment: @JoepBeusenberg Request object is accessible via the Controller object.  The Request.Properties collection allows storing arbitrary data.

Comment: @DarrelMiller, that's not really the same, because that would require you to pass around the controller or the request object to other assemblies. That's exactly what we're trying to avoid with .Current.

Comment: @JoepBeusenberg Creating separate assemblies that only work when they are called from an assembly that is executing within the context of a HTTP request of one particular web stack seems like it might make testing, maintenance and reuse a challenge.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Quite the contrary. I have separated business logic from the actual web project. Using dependency injection I can add a webapi-aware library on top of the business logic. But this library breaks when the business logic has done `.ConfigureAwait(false)` somewhere down the line. There is no request or controller explicitly handed through the business layer, since that one is not web-aware. This is useful for example for a logging module that can inject the request details when the business logic writes a generic `TraceInformation`.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Please ensure you are writing an ASP.NET *4.5* application, and targeting 4.5. `async` and `await` have undefined behavior on ASP.NET unless you are running on 4.5 *and* are using the new "task-friendly" synchronization context.

In particular, this means you must either:

- Set `httpRuntime.targetFramework` to `4.5`, or
- In your `appSettings`, set `aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` to `true`.

More information is [available here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190112220053/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/).

Comment: I am definitely on .NET 4.5

Comment: I just created a new ASP.NET 4.5 WebAPI project, copy/pasted your code, and did a test. It worked perfectly for me (neither exception was thrown). Please re-check that you are running on *and targeting* 4.5.

Comment: I have Target framework: .NET Framework 4.5 set. I don't know what to tell you, it's definitely null on my local machine.

Comment: I did already mention it twice (the first time [with a link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx)), but just to emphasize: you have to target 4.5 in the web.config. ASP.NET 4.5 introduced a "quirks mode" on the server side and you *have* to turn that off to get `async`/`await` working correctly. See the link for all the gory details.

Comment: the `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />` is what solved it, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Yes, in my [`async` on the server side talk](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/slides-available-thatconference-2013.html) I use the Picard WTF?! meme when I talk about the quirks mode on the server. :)

Comment: Does not work with .NET 4.5.1? I had to downgrade to 4.5 to make the sample code in this question to work (after puting httpRuntime.targetFramework to 4.5 in Web.Config)

Comment: @Vince: 4.5.1 should work fine. I'm not sure if you should/could set `targetFramework` to 4.5.1 or 4.5, but async on 4.5.1 should work fine.

Comment: It must be mentioned, that using ConfigureAwait(false) in action method will make HttpContext.Current = null. It's obvious but still.

Comment: What if you wrote your own managed handler?  I keep coming up with HttpContext.Current=null in there even after adding these items in the web.config.

Comment: @Brain2000: I have no experience with that, but from what I understand it *should* work. Try to reduce your code to a minimal repro and post it as a question.

Comment: @StephenCleary If I find it's not easy to find, I will.  You clearly know your stuff in this area!  If anyone can find the answer, it would be you.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary, the exception is thrown here due to different implementation in the frameworks i.e. >=4.5 and frameworks < 4.5 ? If so there should be a KB article from Microsoft regarding this ?

Comment: @Necromancer: A KB article wouldn't be out of the question. The information is a bit hard to find right now. OTOH, .NET 4.0 is considered quite old at this point.

Comment: I have my WebAPI project set to 4.6 and some class library projects that are referenced are set to targetFramwork to 4.5 and have specified in my system.web <httpRuntime targetFramework = "4.6" /> and <compilation targetFramework="4.6". In my appSettings, I have <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />. I don't have .ConfigureAwait anywhere in my solution and yet HttpContext is null for me. Can someone help? @StephenCleary

Comment: @Rahul: Please post a question with a minimal, reproducible example, and we'll be able to help you.

Comment: @Rahul the same for me! my action is `Task<IActionResult>` and the `HttpContext.Current` is null **before** the await function, I mean, whaat? I tried everything here... .net 4.6.1

Comment: @JobaDiniz: Can you post a question with a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: Dear @StephenCleary , I know you the best in mltithreading and asynchronous topics. I want to ask you if you find it helpfull, do some clarification in my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/61756617/9212040
thanks in advance

Answer (score 33):

As @StephenCleary correctly pointed out, you need this in your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

When I was first troubleshooting this, I did a solution-wide search for the above, confirmed it was present in all my web projects and quickly dismissed it as the culprit. Eventually it occurred to me to look at those search results in full context:

```
<!--
  For a description of web.config changes for .NET 4.5 see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

  The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
    <system.Web>
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.Web>
-->
```

Doh.

Lesson: If you upgrade a web project to 4.5, you still need to get that setting in place manually.

Comment: Another gotcha is this is different from <compilation targetFramework"4.5" />

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue recently. As Stephen pointed out not setting explicitly the target framework can generate this issue.

In my case, our Web API was migrated to version 4.6.2 but the runtime target framework was never specified in the web config, so basically this was missing inside the <system.web> tag:

If you have doubts about the framework version you are running this may help:
Add the following line on any of your Web API methods and set a breakpoint to verify what type is currently loaded at runtime and verify it is not a Legacy implementation:

You should see this (AspNetSynchronizationContext):

[image]

Instead of LegazyAspNetSynchronizationContext (Which was what I saw before adding the target framework):

[image]

If you go to the source code (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.cs) you will see that the Legacy implementation of this interface lacks of asynchronous support.

[image]

I spent a lot of time trying to find the source of the issue and Stephen´s response helped a lot. Hope this answer provides some more information about the issue.

Answer (score 3):

> Is my test flawed, or is there some web.config element I'm missing
>   here that would make HttpContext.Current resolve correctly after an
>   await?

Your test is not flawed and HttpContext.Current should not be null after the await because in ASP.NET Web API when you await, this will ensure that the code that follows this await is passed the correct HttpContext that was present before the await.

Comment: Are you sure about the same continuation thread for WebAPI? I dealt with the [case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18284998/1768303) where it was a different thread.

Comment: ASP.NET will resume on any thread pool thread, but with the correct request context.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the thread might not be the same but HttpContext.Current will be the same as before the await. I have updated my question.

Comment: HttpContext.Current is null after an await in my code, and I'm targetting .net 4.6.1.

Comment: Same problem here still.  4.6.1

Comment: for me HttpContext.Current is null **before** an await function

Comment: Me too HttpContext.Current is gone 4.8

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment and say that the previous answers hit the nail on the head *from a web.config perspective*, however, there can be inherited settings from IIS that can override this functionality if you simply use `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />`.

What I mean:
The true fix here is this setting:
`<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />`

If you don't explicitly include this setting but rely on `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />` to configure this setting - it will be overridden by any settings in IIS.

If you are debugging or logging the type of SynchronizationContext and you find out it's of type Legacy, you may want to check for a setting at the IIS or hosting Site level.

### Will yield LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext:

Web.config:

```
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="aspnet:UseLegacyEncryption" value="true" />
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
```

[image]

### Will yield AspNetSynchronizationContext (this is what you want):

```
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
    <add key="aspnet:UseLegacyEncryption" value="true" />
    <add key="aspnet:UseLegacyMachineKeyEncryption" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
```

*Note there is no override setting in IIS here

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the other answers here and `HttpContext.Current` was still null.

.net Framework 4.6.1 / MVC

I'm using `HttpContext.Current` to get the mapped path for an upload to `App_Data`

This is how I fixed the issue:

I just obtain the current `HttpContext.Current` in a variable and then reset it after my `await` calls.

```
var tempHttpContextCurrent = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

var report = await reportingUtilities.GetReport(reportId, currentUserRubixId).ConfigureAwait(false);

// reset the HttpContext.Current after the await call.
System.Web.HttpContext.Current = tempHttpContextCurrent;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was I forget await in the begining of stack, explicity in my constructor action method

**NOTE**: Using net core 5.0 with IHttpContextAccessor

So the problem was in code...

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task AnyAction()
{
    await service.MethodReturningTask(); //await was not
}
```