# HttpContext.Current null inside async task

Tags: c#, ninject, async-await, httpcontext

I have a method that uses a repository (`userRepo`):

```
    public override Task<IdentityResult> CreateLocalUserAsync(IUser user, string password, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var task = new Task<IdentityResult>(() => {

            TUserEntity newUser = new TUserEntity
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                UserName = user.UserName,
                Password = password
            };

            userRepo.Save(newUser).Flush();

            return new IdentityResult(true);
        }, cancellationToken);

        task.Start();

        return task;
    }
```

The `userRepo`object has a dependency that uses `HttpContext.Current`.  Both of these are resolved using ninject `InRequestScope`.

The above method is called inside the default `AccountController` in Mvc 5:

```
var result = await IdentityManager.Users.CreateLocalUserAsync(user, model.Password);
```

I have tried adding this setting to web.config:

```
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
```

Also, I am definitely using .NET 4.5.  This is also in my web.config:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

It is not possible to get the information from the `HttpContext` before I start the task because a dependency of the `userRepo` in the task is using the information and both objects are resolved using Ninject.

How can I ensure that `HttpContext.Current` will not be null?

Comment: “How can I ensure that `HttpContext.Current` will not be null?” Don't use `Task`s or `async`-`await` at all. It doesn't improve anything in this case.

Comment: @svick well, `await` is http-context aware, at least; the problem here is that `Task.Start` isn't.

Comment: Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383923/why-is-httpcontext-current-null-after-await

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "task friendly sync context" here applies to the continuation from the `await`: whatever you do with `result`, it will have the http-context. It does *not*, however, relate to `task.Start`. That relates to the [`TaskScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx), not the sync-context.

Basically, by performing this on a worker, you are (in the process, as a consequence) divorcing that worker from the http-context. You must either:

- get the information you need from the http-context and pass that *into* the worker, or
- don't use a worker

Personally, I doubt you're gaining much by pushing this onto a worker. If you really want to go `async`, the ideal would be for your repo to internally support `*Async` methods. That requires more than using threads: it usually means architectural changes, for example, using async SQL methods. Something written from the ground up to use `async` and sync-context-aware continuations (aka `await`) would automatically preserve things like the http-context.

The important difference here is that an `async`/`await` implementation is linear but not continuous, i.e.

```
 <===(work)==>
                    <===(callback; more work)===>
                                                     <===(another callback)===>
```

where-as your existing code potentially performs things *in parallel*, i.e.

```
<==========(original work)=================>
         <===========(task on worker thread)=============>
```

The fact that the `async`/`await` approach is *basically* linear makes it far more suitable for access to things like http-context, since it knows that (done right) there will only be one thread at a time accessing it - even if it isn't the same thread end-to-end.