# SimpleInjector RegisterWebApiRequest vs RegisterPerWebRequest

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, simple-injector

The latest version of SimpleInjector introduced a distinction between MVC and WebApi.  Are the two request registrations aliases for the same thing?  Or is there underlying differences as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The lifestyles and scope implementations `WebRequest` and `WebApiRequest` in SimpleInjector 2.5 are based on different technologies.

**`WebApiRequestLifestyle`** is derived from `ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle` which works well both inside and outside of IIS. I.e. it can function in a self-hosted WebAPI project where there is no `HttpContext.Current`. The scope used by `WebApiRequestLifestyle` is `ExecutionContextScope`. As the name implies an `ExecutionContextScope` registers itself in the logical call context and flows with `async` operations across threads  (e.g. a continuation after `await` on a different thread still has access to the scope regardless of whether `ConfigureAwait()` was used with `true` or `false`).

In contrast, an instance of **`WebRequestLifestyle`** is stored within the `HttpContext`. The `HttpContext` can be used with WebAPI when it is hosted in IIS but care must be taken because it will not always flow with the execution context because the current `HttpContext` is stored in the *`IllogicalCallContext`* (see [Understanding SynchronizationContext in ASP.NET](http://vegetarianprogrammer.blogspot.de/2012/12/understanding-synchronizationcontext-in.html)). If you use `await` with `ConfigureAwait(false)` the continuation may lose track of the original `HttpContext` whenever the async-op does not execute synchronously. A direct effect of this is that it would no longer be possible to resolve the instance of a previously created service with `WebRequestLifestyle` from the container (e.g. in a factory that has access to the container) - and an exception would be thrown because `HttpContext.Current` would be `null`.

I would recommend you use `WebApiRequestLifestyle` for services that should be 'per Web API request', the most obvious example being services that are injected into WebAPI controllers. `WebApiRequestLifestyle` offers the following benefits:

- the WebAPI controller can be used outside of IIS (e.g. in a self-hosted project)
- the WebAPI controller can execute *free-threaded* (or *multi-threaded*) `async` methods because it is not limited to the ASP.net `SynchronizationContext`.

Check out the blog entry of Stephen Toub regarding the [difference between `ExecutionContext` and `SynchronizationContext`](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx).

Comment: +1. I certainly couldn't have described it better myself. I will probably copy your answer directly to the Simple Injector wiki.

Comment: What about services that are injected into both MVC controller and WebAPI controllers? Is it safe to use PerWebApiRequest for all the services I currently use PerWebRequest?