# MiniProfiler with Web.API 2; is there a global magic request context object?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpcontext, action-filter, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm trying to setup MiniProfiler on my web api site, and having a hard time getting `MiniProfiler.Current` to work.

I followed the directions at miniprofiler.com, and have the following in global.asax:

```cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
  MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
  // other setup
}
protected void Application_BeginRequest() {
  // need to start one here in order to render out the UI
  MiniProfiler.Start();
}
protected void Application_EndRequest() {
  MiniProfiler.Stop();
}
```

This uses the default [WebRequestProfilerProvider](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/WebRequestProfilerProvider.cs), which stores the actual profile object in `HttpContext.Current.Items`.

When I ask for `MiniProfiler.Current`, it looks to `HttpContext.Current`.

When I make a request for one of my web api URLs:

- `Application_BeginRequest` creates the profiler, store it in `HttpContext.Current`
- in a web api `MessageHandler`, I can see `HttpContext.Current`
- in a web apu `IActionFilter`, `HttpContext.Current` is now null, and my attempt to `MiniProfiler.Current.Step("controller:action")` fails
- my EF queries run from various services do not get recorded, as that miniprofiler hook relies `MiniProfiler.Current`, which relies on `HttpContext.Current`, which is null right now
- `Application_EndRequest` fires, and `HttpContext.Current` is magically back, and so it wraps up the profiler and tells me how long it's been since the request began

I dug through the code, and I can create my own `IProfileProvider`, to store the profiler object somewhere more reliable than `HttpContext.Current`, but I don't know where that could be.

I spent a few hours trying things out, but couldn't find a workable solution. The problems:

- the `IProfileProvider` is a global variable; all worker threads in either the MVC or Web API pipeline all have to use the same `IProfileProvider`
- I can dig around in web api RequestContext.Properties to pull out the HttpContext for that request, but that doesn't really help because my `IProfileProvider` is global across the entire app; If I tell it to store the profile in HttpContext A, then any simultaneous requests for other HttpContexts are going to pollute the profile
- I can't rely on any kind of threadstorage because of async/await re-using threads dynamically
- I can't stick the profiler object in an Ninject binding with `InRequestScope` because `InRequestScope` doesn't seem to work with web api 2.1, but even if I could
- everyone says `HttpRequestMessage.Properties` is the new `HttpContext.Current.Items`, but again, `IProfileProvider` is a global variable and I don't know of a way to ensure each request is looking at their version `HttpRequestMessage`. `MiniProfiler.Current` can be called from anywhere, so I guess a global `IProfileProvider` would have to somehow inspect the call stack to and find an `HttpRequestMessage` there? That sounds like madness.

I'm at a loss. What I really want is a [special variable](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/dec_special.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of putting the question together I figured it out. `HttpContext.Current` can get lost when you async/await things: [Why is HttpContext.Current null after await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383923)

I had to make the web.config change listed there, and adjusted my filters to use `Miniprofiler.Current` before any `await`ing.

Also discussed at https://www.trycatchfail.com/2014/04/25/using-httpcontext-safely-after-async-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/