# InRequestScope fails to work in context of ExceptionLogger

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject, asp.net-web-api2, ninject.web

I have a custom Web API ExceptionLogger which is added in WebApiConfig like so:

```
config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new CustomExceptionLogger(kernel.Get<ILoggerFactory>());
```

CustomExceptionLogger is:

```
public class CustomExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _logFactory;

    public CustomExceptionLogger(ILoggerFactory log)
    {
        _logFactory = log;
    }

    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        var log = _logFactory.Create();
        log.LogError("Unhandled exception: {0}",
            context.Exception);
    }
}
```

Ninject bindings are:

```
Bind<ILogger>().ToMethod(CreateLogger)
    .InRequestScope();
Bind<ILoggerFactory>().ToFactory();
```

I am using the Ninject.Extensions.Factory extension. The ILoggerFactory interface is:

```
public interface ILoggerFactory
{
    ILogger Create();
}
```

When Log() is called, I want the ILoggerFactory to return an instance of ILogger which is scoped to the request. However, in this case, I receive back a new ILogger instance that is different to the other instance which has been used elsewhere where ILoggerFactory is used. This seems to be due to `HttpContext.Current` being `null` in the Log() method. This is despite the fact that the ExceptionLoggerContext object contains a Request object (so this method has some context of request, just not the actual HttpContext).

I am using IIS/Web Host versions of Web API 2.2/Ninject 3.2.2.

How can I get InRequestScope() to work correctly in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this behaviour was a consequence of the following:

[Why is HttpContext.Current null after await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383923/why-is-httpcontext-current-null-after-await)

Adding `targetFramework="4.5"` to httpRuntime in web.config caused HttpContext to no longer be null in this method. This consequently fixed the behaviour of InRequestScope().

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```