# Get bearer access token in api logging

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

i am using web api mvc 5 and i am doing api call logging. Following is a snippet

```
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var corrId = string.Format("{0}{1}", DateTime.Now.Ticks, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        var requestInfo = string.Format("{0};{1}", request.Method, request.RequestUri);

        var requestMessage = await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        await IncommingMessageAsync(corrId, requestInfo, requestMessage);

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        byte[] responseMessage;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            responseMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        else
            responseMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response.ReasonPhrase);

        await OutgoingMessageAsync(corrId, requestInfo, responseMessage);

        return response;
    }
```

what i would like to know is how could i get the bearer token if the request is from an authenticated used. I tried HttpContext.Current.User but it's always null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18384253/4753489

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your token is coming in the header as Authorization key then you can pull the bearer token from the header of the request:

```
 if (Request.Headers.Contains("Authorization"))
       var bearerToken = Request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using NET6 this was my approach (also assuming token via header as Authorization key):

```cs
JwtSecurityToken token = null;

if (Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("Authorization"))
{
    StringValues values;

    if (Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out values))
    {
        var jwt = values.ToString();

        if (jwt.Contains("Bearer"))
        {
            jwt = jwt.Replace("Bearer", "").Trim();
        }

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        token = handler.ReadJwtToken(jwt);
    }
}

if (token == null)
{
    return Unauthorized();
}
```