# How to make sure HttpContext.Current is not lost during IdentityServer notifications

Tags: asp.net-core, session-state, httpcontext, synchronizationcontext

I have a scenario where I am using a notification event in my client in the setup code is very simple as follows. This is a AspNet Mvc 4.72 client that uses AspNetCore IdentityServer4:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = "members",
    ...
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {

        SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
        {
            ... 
            // Sometimes this is null but I have to make sure it is 
            // always available so I can initialize stuff here.
            HttpContext.Current.<Use context here>;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
});
```

Actually, more specifically I need access to the session state but it doesn't matter there are some other needs directly related. I am not really sure why this happens but from my research it has something to do with SynchronizationContext and the lifetime of a AspNet Mvc request.

If anyone has a definitive answer about how to ensure the HttpContext's existence please let me know.

Comment: You will have to clarify more about what kind of things you are using there. That is not ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383923/why-is-httpcontext-current-null-after-await

Comment: <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" /> worked for me