# IIS worker thread vs web application thread

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, async-await, threadpool

I'm maintaining an `ASP.NET Core` web application that needs to repeatedly run some background threads. I know it's not a good design but currently I have to fix its major issues with minimum effort. Now I wonder if I should worry about handling users http requests by web server or not?

Question is simple but I can't find any clear answer for it:

**What is the difference between threads that are created in application like this:**

```
Task.Run(() => { // some parallel job })
```

**and worker threads of IIS that handle http requests?**

Are they come from the same thread pool or they're reside in separate pools?

Comment: Web servers are designed to take a request, handle it and return quickly and should not be used for 'intensive' code.  IMO these worker tasks should be running on a different (non-web) server, so that they don't interfere with the job of serving web pages.

Comment: @Neil You're completely right but focus of question is more on differences between two type of threads and their relation and impacts on each other

Comment: They are basically the same. But you shouldn't do it on a web server application. Every time you do it, you kill performance and availability.

Comment: @PauloMorgado I agree that it's not a good design, this system is designed years ago and currently I have to solve its issues with minimum effort. Could you explain iis threads and app threads relation in more details? if they are the same it's confusing for me that how they can interact with managed app domain and unmanaged http request contexts!

Comment: In general, if you use `Task.Run` on a web server, it's because you're doing something that shouldn't be done handling a web request. If you block the current thread on top of that, then you're gaining nothing for double the cost. Threads that handle requests, threads that handle I/O callbacks, threads that run async continuations and `Task.Run` all use threads from the same thread pool. If you waste them, you make the whole application slower and might even cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-3.1) it's all one pool: "ASP.NET Core already runs app code on normal Thread Pool threads." In other words, there isn't a separate max for threads serving requests vs. background threads.

The biggest difference is that IIS is aware of the threads it creates itself for an incoming request. IIS is not aware of any threads you create yourself.

When an app pool is recycled, or IIS is shut down, it waits until all requests have finished processing - it waits until the threads it creates for each request has finished processing - and then it kills the process. If you create any threads that outlive the request (for example, if you create a background thread and then send the response back to the client) IIS has no idea that thread is still running and could kill the whole process at any time.

If you don't return a response until all the threads are complete, then you won't have that specific problem.

The other issue is that you may hit the maximum number of allowable threads. Then all kinds of weird performance issues would happen. But that depends on how many threads you are creating and how many HTTP requests are coming in.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel for your answer, So you say both of these type of threads reside in the common `Thread Pool` right? Can we set any max number limitation for IIS worker threads and application background threads **separately** to protect them from exploding each other?!

Comment: You tagged ASP.NET Core. Are you using Core or just regular ASP.NET? It may also depend on if you are running the Core application it in-process or not.

Comment: It's `ASP.NET Core`. Currently it's host as `In-Process` but I'll be thankfull if you could also explain differences of this with `Out of Process`

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-3.1) it's all one pool: "ASP.NET Core already runs app code on normal Thread Pool threads." In other words, there isn't a separate max for threads serving requests vs. background threads.