# UserContext becomes null after async call

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service call in my function `Verify`.
The code is as follows:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    ....
    
    UserContext.LoginUser = null;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(etoken))
    {
        SSOLogin ssoLogin = new SSOLogin();
        LoginUser user = await ssoLogin.Verify(etoken);
        UserContext.LoginUser = user;
        if (UserContext.LoginUser == null)
            return RedirectToAction("UnAuthorized", "Login");
        else
        {
            Session["authenticated"] = true;
            userId = UserContext.LoginUser.UserId;
            domain = UserContext.LoginUser.Domain;
        }
    }
}

public async Task<LoginUser> Verify(string etoken)
{
    string publicKey = "xxx";

    LoginUser loginUser = null;

    WSVerifyAccessToken wsVerifyAccessToken = new WSVerifyAccessToken();
    string verifyResponse = await wsVerifyAccessToken.VerifyAccessToken(etoken); // Inside, this is a web service call

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(verifyResponse))
    {
        /* Some processing here */
    }


    return loginUser;
}
```

The problem is that, the UserContext becomes null after the `Verify` function

```
LoginUser user = await ssoLogin.Verify(etoken);
```

Hence when I assign

```
UserContext.LoginUser = user;
```

gives me the error `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`.

I tried to make the function to be synchronous

```
LoginUser user = await ssoLogin.Verify(etoken).Result;
```

but then the web service call will just hang there and never finishes.

Any solution?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue when the ***runtime*** target framework is 4.0, and not 4.5 or above, in the web.config file. This can differ from the target framework your project is set up for. [Make sure that the runtime target framework is 4.5 or higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383923/why-is-httpcontext-current-null-after-await).

Additionally:
The UserContext is bound to the Thread initializing the Request. Therefore, you should return the callback of your awaited call to the original context. Even though the ConfigureAwait(true) is the default value, you should ensure the correct context is used in the callback by specifying the following:

```
UserContext.LoginUser = await ssoLogin.Verify(etoken).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

See a more detailed description regarding the configure await method [here](https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f)

Comment: Isn't `.ConfigureAwait(true);` the default?

Comment: @mjwills, ah yes, you are correct. My Roslyn analyzers have driven me to the point where I'm always explicit about this :).

Comment: @rcs, also, check your runtime target framework in the web.config settings. I've updated my answer with references. This could differ from the framework version of your project.

Comment: What if I'm using 4.7? I try not to downgrade my .net framework version

Comment: There is a difference between the Target version and the Runtime version. Just make sure the RUNTIME version isn't set to 4.0 by any chance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218353/discussion-between-thomas-luijken-and-rcs).

Comment: I added this `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" />` in the Web.config and it solves the problem. No need the `ConfigureAwait(true)`

Comment: Hi @rcs, I'm happy to hear adding the runtime targetFramework setting helped!
Please mark this anwser as the correct answer. I would help other users get on the right track. I'll update the anwer accordingly.