# WebMethod async Results Show Object

Tags: c#, jquery, async-await, webmethod

I am trying to return results using async but instead of returning the data I want it returns the entire object

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(BufferResponse=false)]
public static async Task<bool> getLogin(string username, string password)
{
    Login login = new Login();
    Task<bool> loginVerify = login.verifyLogin(username,password);
    await loginVerify;
    return loginVerify.Result;
}

public class Login
{
    public async Task<bool> verifyLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The results from Firefox Firebug show this :

```
{"d":{"Result":true,"Id":2,"Exception":null,"Status":5,"IsCanceled":false,"IsCompleted":true,"CreationOptions":0,"AsyncState":null,"IsFaulted":false}}
```

Why isn't it just showing the result?

I tried running

```
public static async Task<bool> getLogin(string username, string password)
{
    Login login = new Login();
    Task<bool> loginVerify = login.verifyLogin(username,password);
    await loginVerify;
    return false;
}
```

but the firebug report was the same except it said Result false in the json

```
{"d":{"Result":false,"Id":2,"Exception":null,"Status":5,"IsCanceled":false,"IsCompleted":true,"CreationOptions":0,"AsyncState":null,"IsFaulted":false}}
```

So my question is why does it show the whole object instead of just the result?

Comment: Do WebMethods support `async-await`?

Comment: I assume so since I am getting results and in the results I have the correct reply. It just keeps sending the entire object instead of just the Result. Its kinda of baffling to me.....

Comment: That tells me that `async-await` is not supported. And you should read more about `async-await`.

Comment: i would assume if it wasn't supported it would return the answer. I mean don't get me wrong I could sort through the object in jquery and get the result but I was hoping someone knew why it returns the full object then just the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18623705/41071), `WebMethod` does not support `async`-`await` (it does support another async pattern, APM, and you can convert `async`-`await` to APM, but it's quite awkward).

So why do you get such weird result? `WebMethod` does not know that `Task` is some special type, so it treats it just like a regular object, by accessing and serializing its properties. This includes `Result`, which synchronously returns the result of the `Task`. This also means that the code is not actually asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

please convert the result to json before returning it.You can use any json convert to that

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(BufferResponse=false)]
public static async Task<bool> getLogin(string username, string password)
{
    Login login = new Login();
    Task<bool> loginVerify = login.verifyLogin(username,password);
    await loginVerify;
    var result= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(loginVerify.Result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: dont forget to add reference to System.Web.Extensions

Comment: I followed this but it still gives me the full object instead of just the result

Here is the reply i got from the code you posted 

`{"d":{"Result":"true","Id":2,"Exception":null,"Status":5,"IsCanceled":false,"IsCompleted":true,"CreationOptions"
:0,"AsyncState":null,"IsFaulted":false}}`

Comment: This won't compile: `result` is a `string`, but it needs to be `bool` to compile. And trying to serialize a `Task` doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: it compiled for me. I just changed the Task from bool to string

Comment: @ArcSet But you didn't change that in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather simple, consider the following:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(BufferResponse=false)]
public static async Task<bool> getLogin(string username, string password)
{
    Login login = new Login();
    Task<bool> loginVerify = login.verifyLogin(username, password);
    return await loginVerify;
}

public class Login
{
    public async Task<bool> verifyLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When `getLogin` is invoked it will instantiate the `Login` class and call into the `.verifyLogin` method, this returns a `Task<bool>` -- which means it's "awaitable". When you `await` it, you are given the `boolean` result value.

This could be simplified to return the `Task<bool>` wholesale, since there is a single `Task` in question. Treat the `Task` as a single asynchronous operation and return it -- allowing the consumer to `await` it:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(BufferResponse=false)]
public static Task<bool> getLogin(string username, string password)
{
    Login login = new Login();
    return login.verifyLogin(username, password);
}

async Task FooBar()
{
    boolean isLoggedIn = await _loginService.getLogin(this.Username, this.Password);
}
```

**Notes**

1. Try to avoid using `Task.Result`, even if it has been awaited.
2. Postfix async methods (`Task` or `Task<T>` returning) with "Async".

Comment: I ran this and it still returns the full object to the browser.

Firebug results
`{"d":{"Result":true,"Id":2,"Exception":null,"Status":5,"IsCanceled":false,"IsCompleted":true,"CreationOptions"
:0,"AsyncState":null,"IsFaulted":false}}`

Comment: What would you suggest I would need to do to get JSON configured.

Comment: I'm not sure what firebug is doing but I believe that it's incorrect, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367054/creating-an-async-webservice-method. This is an example of it working as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but just want to share a solution.
in Javascript we can use response.d.Result to get actual string from c#.
For example:

```
success: function (response) {
                    var gJson = eval(response.d.Result);
                    console.log(gJson);
}
```