# How to Reuse FtpWebRequest Connection

Tags: .net, ftpwebrequest

I need to list thousands of files on FTP server, and delete the necessary ones. As you can guess, performance is essential, so I need a way to reuse the FTP connection.

There is not enough explanation on MSDN about the connection usage of FtpWebRequests! It only says "Multiple FtpWebRequests reuse existing connections, if possible." What does "if possible" mean? I want to control when to close connection, simple as that! Any idea?

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Previous connections to the server are reused if possible as long as the `KeepAlive` parameter to the `HttpWebRequest` object is set to `true`.This optimization happens underneath the creation and use of multiple HttpWebRequest objects.

With respect to multithreaded operations, there is a limit on the number of concurrent connection to a particular host.

[`System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388908/improving-performance-of-multithreaded-httpwebrequests-in-net) can used to increase concurrent connections

- [How to improve the Performance of FtpWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016690/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-ftpwebrequest?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: OK, but when does it close the connection?

Comment: GC will take care of closing the `HttpWebRequest` but you need to close the `HttpWebResponse`