# Reusing FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to make a simple method to download a file from an FTP using `FtpWebRequest` with the method `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile`. The problem is that I wan't to display the progress of downloading and thus need to know the file size ahead to be able to calculate the percentage transfered. But when I call `GetResponse` in `FtpWebRequest` the `ContentLength` member is -1.

OK - so I get the size of the file in advance using the method `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize`. No problem. Then after getting the size I download the file.

This is where the problem in question appears...

After getting the size I try to reuse the `FtpWebRequest` and resets the method to `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile`. This causes an `System.InvalidOperationException` saying something like "Can't perform this action after sending the request." (may not be the exact formulation - translated from the one I get in Swedish).

I've found elsewhere that as long as I set the `KeepAlive` property to true, it doesn't matter, the connection is kept active. This is what I don't understand... The only object I've created is my `FtpWebRequest` object. And if I create another one, how can it know what connection to use? And what credentials?

Pseudo code:

```
Create FtpWebRequest
Set Method property to GetFileSize
Set KeepAlive property to true
Set Credentials property to new NetworkCredential(...)
Get FtpWebResponse from the request
Read and store ContentLength
```

Now I got the file size. So it's time to download the file. Setting Method now causes the exception mentioned above. So do I create a new `FtpWebRequest`? Or is there anyway to reset the request to be reused? (Closing the response made no difference.)

I don't understand how to move forward without re-creating the object. I could do that, but it just doesn't feel right. So i'm posting here in hope to find the correct way of doing this.

Here's the (non working) code (Inputs are sURI, sDiskName, sUser and sPwd.) :

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(sURI);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(sUser, sPwd);
request.UseBinary = true;
request.UsePassive = true;
request.KeepAlive = true;

FtpWebResponse resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
int contLen = (int)resp.ContentLength;
resp.Close();

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream inStr = resp.GetResponseStream();
byte[] buff = new byte[16384];

sDiskName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(sDiskName);
FileStream file = File.Create(sDiskName);

int readBytesCount;
int readTotal=0;

while ((readBytesCount = inStr.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length)) > 0)
{
    readTotal += readBytesCount;
    toolStripProgressBar1.Value = 100*readTotal/contLen;
    Application.DoEvents();
    file.Write(buff, 0, readBytesCount);
}
file.Close();
```

I hope someone can explain how this is supposed to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: At least with HTTPWebRequests - you always have to create a new one. Suppose same problem here.

Comment: `FtpWebRequest` is good for making single requests. You want an FTP client, which connects and maintains a persistent connection until you close it. `System.Net.FtpClient` seems well regarded: http://netftp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this will be answered so I'm "closing it" by telling you how I solved it.

Well, I didn't really solve it. I did however test the download by recreating the `FtpWebRequest` and noticed that on the FTP server it behaved as I wanted i.e. only one log on and then sequentially executing my requests.

This is how the code getting the file size and starting the download ended up:

```
// Start by fetching the file size
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(sURI);

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(sUser, sPwd);
request.Credentials = nc;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.UsePassive = true;
request.KeepAlive = true;

// Get the result (size)
FtpWebResponse resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Int64 contLen = resp.ContentLength;

// and now download the file
request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(sURI);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
request.Credentials = nc;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.UsePassive = true;
request.KeepAlive = true;

resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

So no answer on if it's possible to reset the `FtpWebRequest` for re-use. But at least I know there's no redundant information being transferred.

Thanks to everybody who took an interest and spent time thinking of an answer.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7132428/2170171 sheds some light on how that supposed to work, so basically you are doing the 'right' thing. And this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/9666598/2170171 shows how to trace FTP request, so you can see that connection is really reused between requests

Answer (score 5):

FtpWebRequest can be used for only 1 request, like getting the file size or to download the file, but not both. You have to create 2 FtpWebRequests. Behind the scene, FtpWebRequest notices that it is the same URL and credentials and will reuse the same ftp connection without closing it, as long IsKeepAlieve is true, which is the default setting.

This is a sad example of bad design by Microsoft. Instead of letting us explicitly open and close a connection, they want to do it automatically for us and confuse everyone.

Comment: Just to clarify, Is it not possible with FtpWebRequest to send say 10 files WITHOUT logging in 10 times?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to probably want to use the Async method. Here's the link to the MSDN doc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx

```
GetResponseAsync()
```

That will keep your application from locking up too, so you won't have to use

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

You could also look at possibly using an alternative ftp library. imo the FtpWebRequest is not exactly the best ftp class. A quick search turned up this library. Ftp isn't stateless like HTTP. I prefer libraries that let you create a client, open a connect, and keep the connection alive.

http://sanity-free.org/dist/NullFX.Net-binary.zip

Here's the code exacmple I found

```
FtpClient client = 
    new FtpClient( 
        new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Loopback, 21 ), 
        new NetworkCredential( "test", "testing@localdomain" ) 
    );
client.Connect();
client.Download("testfile.zip", @"C:\downloads\testfile.zip");
```

The source is there too, so you would be able to possibly attach some events to the read process for your download progress tracking.

Comment: In this case I'm a bit reluctant to use third party products. And I'm well aware of the inner workings of FTP as I've written both servers and client libraries from scratch. What I'm after here is to know if it's possible to do with `FtpWebRequest`. If not, I guess I'll go with the Asynch approach (which I opted out on earlier because of the added complexity to the code). Bit of a shame though to complicate it like that, when I'm not really after asynchronous behaviour, apart from the progress bar update... Thanks anyway.